# Moving cells if value greater than other value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for help on something I can't find anywhere else... I've tried a few different stuff but nothing works.
Could someone please help and tell me how to **move a group of cells if a value is greater than another ?**

[Here is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxxmM.jpg)

And I want Team B to move to rank 1 above of Team A if they have more points. So if Team B > Team A swap them around.

Thanks for your help,
Max.

Comment: Formulae cannot 'move' the contents of a cell. You will need to write VB script to do that. This said, you can use filtering and sorting, although that's a slightly more manual process.

Comment: Order your data from max to min, using the points column.

Comment: If you have the source data on one sheet, then you cold use the large() function on another sheet to display the teams in order...